I'd like to change the sentence structure when <-> until

#1 I will do my homework when I have time.


#2 I won't do my homework until I have time.

I think #1,#2 are the same meaning

#3 I won’t let you play outside until you’ve done your homework.


#4 when you have done your homework I'll let you play outside

And, #3,#4 are the same meaning.
Can I change like this? thanks in advance.

Both sentences in each pair have the same effective meaning, but a different tone.
"I won't do X until Y happens" sounds like a defiant child (2) or a stern parent (3), while "I will do X when Y has happened" (1 and 4) is a promise, and much more positive.
